# How to integrate QT with novint falcon?

Tags: c++, qt, falcon

Novint falcon is integrated using the HDAL SDK on Visual Studio. I could not find any documentation online to install the SDK on QT. I tried to include the HDAl library and header files in my QT project. The .pro file looks like this.The error is

:-1: error: No rule to make target '../imagesegment/hdl.h', needed by 'debug/main.o'.  Stop.

```css
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-11-04T14:24:33
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = imagesegment
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    haptics.cpp \
    gshaptics.cpp \
    main_dx9.cpp \
    main_opengl.cpp \
    StdAfx.cpp

HEADERS += \
    hdl.h \
    hdlConstants.h \
    hdlErrors.h \
    hdlExports.h \
    hdlu.h \
    hdluExports.h \
    adll.h \
    afuncs.h \
    atypes.h \
    avars.h \
    glut.h \
    haptics.h \
    StdAfx.h \
    Widget.h


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/lib/ -lhdl
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/lib/ -lhdld

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/include
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. We need to add the header files and libs as mentioned in the qmake documentation on qt website. Try to save qt in a folder with 'no spaces' in it's path.

```html
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = cube4
QT += 3d
SOURCES = cubeview.cpp main.cpp \
    haptics.cpp
HEADERS = cubeview.h \
    haptics.h \
    src/haptics.h \
    src/adll.h \
    src/afuncs.h \
    src/atypes.h \
    src/avars.h \
    src/glut.h \
    src/StdAfx.h \
    hdl/hdl.h \
    hdl/hdlConstants.h \
    hdl/hdlErrors.h \
    hdl/hdlExports.h \
    hdlu/hdlu.h \
    hdlu/hdluExports.h
HEADERS += \
    Widget.h
RESOURCES = cube.qrc
CONFIG += exceptions

win32:LIBS += $$quote(C:/Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/lib/hdl.lib)


INCLUDEPATH += $$quote("$$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/include/hdl")
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote("$$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/include/hdlu")
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote("$$PWD/../../../../Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/examples/Basic/src")

win32: INCLUDEPATH +="C:/Program Files/Novint/HDAL_SDK_2.1.3/include"
```